# How do I change the culture used by Object.ToString?

Tags: .net, string-formatting, globalization, tostring

It's tedious to write

```
string msg = "Result is " + r.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " with "
    + p.toString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "% probability.";
```

I would prefer

```
string msg = "Result is " + r + " with " + p + "% probability.";
```

How can I set `InvariantCulture` as the default throughout my project?

My goal is to produce *programmer* readable output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the current thread and ui thread cultures to it:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Answer (score -1):

You example shows the formatting of display text, so you should trust the plain version of `ToString()` to format your objects as appropriate to the current culture. Therefore don't specify a culture at all. Don't worry, it's how it's meant to be!

`InvariantCulture` should be reserved for cases where you construct strings that are meant to control logic, not display strings. See for example [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx) which confirms this.

If for some obscure reason you really don't want any variation in your display strings then you can specify a culture, any culture (e.g. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo( "en-US");`), but not `InvariantCulture`.